# Fabric.js object:selected, object not selected

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fabricjs

Using Fabric.js I am working with a text object that I have named header. When the header area is selected a div is faded in with two input fields that can be used to set text and fill. This is working for me.

What I am attempting to handle next, is when deselecting the header object, I will fade out my div. What is the proper way to handle header.off()?

```
header.on('selected', function() {

  $('#header-text-edit').fadeIn('fast');

  // watch for header.input changes
  scope.$watch("header.input", function(value) {
    header.text = scope.header.input;
  });

  // watch for header.color changes
  scope.$watch("header.color", function(value) {
    header.fill = scope.header.color;
  });
});
```

Comment: `header.off()` would be used to _remove_ event handlers. It doesn't have anything to do with the opposite of an event. `on()` adds an event handler, `off()` removes it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need:

```
canvas.on('selection:cleared', function() {
  ...
});
```

Take a look at [Events Demo](http://fabricjs.com/events) and [Events Section](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2#events) in tutorial.

Comment: It's pretty old but just in case someone stumbles upon it - it is important to note that moving from selection to another selection doesn't fire the `'selection:cleared'` event.

Comment: To add to what @NimrodShory mentioned, it seems from moving from a selection to another selection doesn't fire object:selected either... why doesn't it do both?..update: it seems selection:updated helps to see whats is happening...

Answer (score 12):

For [fabricjs 2.0 branch](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/) the events for selection on canvas should be as follows:

```
canvas.on('selection:created', function () {
   //...
});

canvas.on('selection:cleared', function () {
   //...
});
```

the `selected` event is for individual objects on canvas

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 50, fill: 'green' });
rect.on('selected', function() {
    console.log('selected a rectangle');
});
```

Comment: If i click on an element and then immediately click on another without clicking elsewhere iam unable to trigger the `selection:created` for the new element it is only working if the existing elements selection is cleared and next element is clicked, how do i fix this? is there anything else to handle them?

Comment: you might want to observe `selection:updated` event as well.